# Tag picker onChange event not firing

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I'm trying to trigger an event when the user writes something in the input field of [Fluent UI Tag Picker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pickers) but it seems that it's not working for some reason. The documentation provides examples for onFocus event and that one is working fine, however the onChange doesn't seem to work.

I added an onChange callback to the inputProps object

```
const inputProps: IInputProps = {
  onFocus: () => console.log('onFocus called'),
  onChange: () => console.log('onChange Called'),
};
```

And then passed the object as inputProps to the tagPicker

```
<TagPicker
    removeButtonAriaLabel="Remove"
    selectionAriaLabel="Selected colors"
    onResolveSuggestions={filterSuggestedTags}
    getTextFromItem={getTextFromItem}
    pickerSuggestionsProps={pickerSuggestionsProps}
    itemLimit={2}
    disabled={tagPicker}
    inputProps={{
      ...inputProps,
      id: 'picker1',
    }}
  />
```

here is a code pen with the same example from their documentation showing the issue: https://codepen.io/Attias/pen/mdXbmzL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onChange` event triggers when user pick something from suggestions list or remove item from picker. What you can do is to use `onInputChange` event:

```js
<TagPicker
  ...
  onInputChange={value => {
    // Do something.
    return value;
  }}   
/>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/JjpPOWM?editors=0011) working example.

Comment: That works, I tried `onInputChanged` but it was throwing a warning as I wasn't returning value afterwards

Comment: It's important to return value to get state updated ;)